# Saving data in cakephp 3

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I want to save User data in my database but still getting error

data

```
$this->request->data['nickname'] = ' asd';
$this->request->data['first_name'] = ' asd';
$this->request->data['last_name'] = 'asd ';
```

controller

```
$user = $this->Users->newEntity();

$user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->data);

if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
       echo 'saved';
} else {
       echo 'error';
}
```

Comment: What's you error ?

Comment: `newEntity` is wasted if you are overwriting it with a patched entity. also, instead of echo'ing error, I would loop through `$user->errors()` and print those to see what my errors are. 99% chance that it's a validation error. But we need more data.

Comment: @Albert Yep, it was validation, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment:

> Instead of echo'ing error, I would loop through `$user->errors()` and
>   print those to see what my errors are. 99% chance that it's a
>   validation error.